# I am validating for RegEx errors -- how can I return which keyword, it failed on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

I'm passing new objects through this set of regex :

```
(?i)exp\s|(?i)expire\s|(?i)print|(?i)mention|(?i)spring|(?i)summer|(?i)winter|(?i)jan(\s|\.)|(?i)january|(?i)february|(?i)feb(\.|\s)|(?i)march|mar(\.|\s)|(?i)april|(?i)june|(?i)july|(?i)august|(?i)aug(\s|\.)|(?i)september|(?i)sept(\.|\s)|(?i)november|(?i)nov(\.|\s)|(?i)december|(?i)dec(\.|\s)|(?i)holiday|(?i)christmas|(?i)holloween|(?i)easter|(?i)season|(?i)ends|(?i)end
```

If it errors, for example on the word `christmas` , how can I dynamically pull the word it errors on, and display it as the cause of the error?

Comment: There's no such thing as an error on a valid regex. It either finds the pattern in the string (a match) or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$~` will be set to a `MatchData` object. If you then call `$~.captures`, you should get an array of matches.